# Как запомнить пользователя?

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте!) Нужно сделать так чтоб, при первом вводе своих данных (имя и адрес), пользователь мог отметить CheckBox с меткой "Запомнить", и при следующем запуске эти данные в полях уже были введены... Как это можно реализовать?... Мой вариант состоит в том что при запуске программа проверяет каталог на наличие определенного файла, если он есть, то программа считывает с него значения, и вставляет в поля и CheckBox скрывает, иначе же запускается программа с пустыми полями и CheckBox, при щелкание на CheckBox (при условие что введены значения полей), создается файл в который записываются эти значения полей... Если вариант верен, то подскажите как проверить каталог на наличие файла? Спасибо)

Comment: Логика вашего варианта правильная. Про реализацию на Delphi не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверить существование файла можно функцией **FileExists**.
Допустим, у вас есть:

```
 var
  fileName : string;
  textFile : TextFile;
  temp     : string;
```

При запуске проверяете существование и содержимое файла (не забудьте про ситуацию, когда файл существует, но содержит неверные данные, например, только одна строка, пустой, и т.д.).

```
  fileName := 'UserData.txt';
  AssignFile(textFile, fileName);
  Reset(textFile);
  if FileExists(fileName) then
    while not Eof(textFile) do
    begin
      ReadLn(textFile, temp);
      ... // записываем полученные строчки в поля
    end;   
  CloseFile(textFile);
```

Затем запишите, то что ввел пользователь

```
  fileName := 'UserData.txt';
  AssignFile(textFile, fileName);
  ReWrite(textFile);   
  WriteLn(textFile, 'user-name');  // значения из текстовых полей
  WriteLn(textFile, 'user@mail.ru');
  CloseFile(textFile);
```

p.s. файл лучше всего хранить как [user-home]/.ApplicationName/UserData.txt

Answer (score 3):

Можно записывать такие данные в реестр, а лучше получить от системы путь к Application directory (не помню, как звучит точно), создать там свою папку и сохранить такой файл туда, тогда он не будет маячить рядом с экзешником.

Comment: Ну я и хотел файл создать где то в пользовательской директории, к примеру как [user-home]/.ApplicationName/UserData.txt) А как записывать данные в реестр, не подскажите?)

Comment: @Leshij_2005, логичнее это написать как дополнение к вопросу..

Answer (score 1):

О работе с реестром на Delphi

- [есть например тут](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/kol_lesson8.html)
- [или, попроще, тут](http://delphiexpert.ru/view_lesson.php?id=31)

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё использовать ini-файлы (может кто скажет, что устарел, но использовать тоже можно) =)